# Как использовать междоменные запросы при написании расширения для chrome (обход CORS)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Стала задача, написать расширение которое бы работало только на определённых доменах из списка, а сам список был бы получен txt-файлом через get запрос, но беда, браузер блочит ссылаясь на политику CORS...

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://site.org/data.txt' from origin 'https://surge.sh' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

код js

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'https://site.org/data.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) {
    if (client.responseText.split(' ').includes(document.domain)) {
      document.querySelector('.eyeaq-hide').style.display = "none";
    } else { 
      alert ('на этом сайте не работает.');
    }
  }
}
client.send();
```

кто сталкивался с этим, как решить?

суть в том, что скрипт выше будет нормально работать только на домене, где лежит этот файл, но если находится на другом домене и получать по запросу файл, то будет эта самая политика.

Comment: Если у вас есть доступ к серверу, с которого вы берете контент, вы можете разрешить другому сайту брать с него информацию, добавив его в значение заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar браузер как раз и осуществляет соблюдение политики CORS, а значит именно он и блокирует получение данных.

Comment: @2ip сейчас объясню суть расширения. На сайте есть div, что перекрывает содержимое всем, кто заходит из РФ-ip, вместо этого они видят заглушку с текстом. само же расширение создано для того, чтобы у тех, кто его установил эта заглушка скрывалась посредством display:none; и вот, я подумал, что кто-то так же захочет реализовать у себя такое и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы условия срабатывания document.querySelector('.eyeaq-hide').style.display = "none";  работало только на нужных доменах из списка. но похоже, проще просто сделать, чтобы везде работало, где есть класс .eyeaq-hide....

Comment: Для реализации подобного лучше использовать userscript. Он аналогичен расширениям для браузера, но предназначен скорее для небольших решений. Кроме того, ваша работа будет работать не только в chrome, но и в некоторых других браузерах. Свои работы вы сможете опубликовать на специальных сайтах, например Greasy Fork.